# How do I set my web application's context root to "/".

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x, contextroot

I am having trouble setting my context root in my web application.
I would to set context root to "/", but when I start my application server(jboss-5.1.0.GA) I got exception the following exception:

> 12:21:23,257 ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Start: name=jboss.web.deployment:war=/ state=Create mode=Manual requiredState=Installed
>   org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Web mapping already exists for deployment URL file:/D:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/letu-prod/deploy/ATG.ear/store.war/
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:187)
>           at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
>           at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
>           at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
>           at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
>           at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
>           at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
>           at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
>           at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
>           at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
>           at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
>           at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
>           at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>           at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
>           at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
>           at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
>           at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:163)
>           at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:99)
>           at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:46)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
>           at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:702)
>           at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.MainDeployerAdapter.process(MainDeployerAdapter.java:117)
>           at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.ProfileDeployAction.install(ProfileDeployAction.java:70)
>           at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileAction.install(AbstractProfileAction.java:53)
>           at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.install(AbstractProfileService.java:361)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1631)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1082)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
>           at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
>           at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.repository.AbstractProfileService.activateProfile(AbstractProfileService.java:306)
>           at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:271)
>           at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:461)
>           at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:221)
>           at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:556)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Could somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

By default. there is a ROOT.war in the deploy folder of JBoss which gets bound to / context.
Earlier versions of JBoss did not throw an exception when some other application too tried binding its context to /.

Please have a look at the below link

[Web mapping already exists for deployment](https://community.jboss.org/message/250374)

Answer (score 2):

I'm also running jBoss 5.1 with eclipse indigo (STS 2.9.2)  I kept my Web Project Settings to my original root context myWarName.war for example in eclipse, but had to change the jBoss.web.xml file to this:

from:

```
<jboss-web>
     <context-root>myWarName</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

To:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Then I renamed my ROOT.war under my jBoss deploy folder to jBossROOT.war as mentioned in the link from Arun and everything worked.  I didn't want to delete the ROOT.war, so I elected this option.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the context root of the web application (also called the context path) is set to the root name (the name without the .war extension) of the Web Application Archive (WAR). You can override the context root using the standard application descriptor (i.e., application.xml) for EAR deployments or the JBoss AS web descriptor (i.e., jboss-web.xml) for standalone WARs. Let's talk about standalone WARs first.

**Standalone WAR deployment**

You override the context path of the web application (the context root) in a standalone WAR in a jboss-web.xml, located in the WEB-INF directory of the WAR. Here, we are setting the context root to /, which which is known as the root context. When an application is assigned to the root context, it will respond to all requests not handled by a more specific context root.

*/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml (in WAR)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jboss-web>  
    <context-root>/</context-root>  
</jboss-web>
```

There are many other settings this file can configure. Although it's not required, you can add an XSD (or in earlier versions a DTD) to the XML root. Let's add the XSD for JBoss AS 5.1, found in the JBoss AS schema catalog, and change the context root to /myapp.

*/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml (in WAR)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="  
      http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee  
      http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">  
   <context-root>myapp</context-root>  
</jboss-web>
```

(Note: If you have a problem deploying, simply do without the schema declarations).

While the manner in which the context path is set in a standalone WAR is proprietary, Java EE does provide a standard way of assigning a context path to a WAR when deployed in an EAR.

**EAR deployment**

When a web application is deployed inside an EAR file, the context root is specified in the application.xml file of the EAR, using a context-root element inside of a web module. In the following example, the context root of the bank-webapp.war application is set to /mymoney.

*/META-INF/application.xml (in EAR)*

```
<application version="5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
   xsi:schemaLocation="  
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd">  
   <module>  
      <ejb>bank-ejb.jar</ejb>  
   </module>  
   <module>  
      <web>  
         <web-uri>bank-webapp.war</web-uri>  
         <context-root>mymoney</context-root>  
      </web>  
   </module>  
</application>
```

Comment: JBOSS 7.1.1 AS is not detecting "/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml"